# CMake set CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY for a specific target only

Tags: cmake

My whole project uses

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
```

to place all runtime binaries in the `bin` directory.

However i need to place some dll's in a subdirectory named "scripts",
i tried following code to set the variable for the specific target:

```
set_target_properties(my_script_dll PROPERTIES
    CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/scripts"
)
```

But it doesn't work, the dll's are still placed under `bin`.

**Is there a way to set the output directory only for a specific target?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it through using:

```
set_target_properties(my_script_dll PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/scripts"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/scripts"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/RelWithDebInfo/scripts"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/MinSizeRel/scripts"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to previous answer, from my testing it seems this can be done in a shorter way:

```
set_target_properties(my_script_dll PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>/scripts"
)
```